# How to read all the strings first then output it?

Tags: c

I'am using fgets to get inputs.

Input:

station

cricket

expected output:

station

cricket

```
char str[size_limit];
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
}
printf("%s", ??);
```

Comment: please explain your question a bit more clearly.

Comment: Please give the exact input and expected output. Your description is unclear but I suspect you mean you want to read all the input first then output it. If that is the case then you need to have different buffers for each string. e.g. `char strs[max_strings][size_limit];` then `fgets(strs[i], sizeof(strs[i]), stdin);` and finally have a loop that prints each of the strings.

Comment: " I suspect you mean you want to read all the input first then output it. " yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what "compute the outputs" means, but if you want to read all the lines of text in a file and then compute a result from those lines of text, something like this will work (in this case I just print out the lines of text from the in-memory array, but you can modify it as necessary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char ** linesBuf = NULL;
   size_t numSlotsInArray = 0;

   int numLinesRead = 0;
   char buf[512];
   while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
   {
      if (numLinesRead >= numSlotsInArray)
      {
         // Whoops, our allocated array is too short, make it larger
         numSlotsInArray = (numSlotsInArray == 0) ? 100 : (numSlotsInArray*2);
         linesBuf = realloc(linesBuf,  numSlotsInArray*sizeof(char*));
         if (linesBuf == NULL)
         {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(10);
         }
      }
  
      char * nextLine = strdup(buf);
      if (nextLine == NULL)
      {
         perror("strdup");
         exit(10);
      }
      linesBuf[numLinesRead++] = nextLine;
   }

   printf("total number of lines read:  %i\n", numLinesRead);
   for(size_t i=0; i<numLinesRead; i++)
   {
      printf("Line %zu is:  [%s]\n", i, linesBuf[i]);
   }

   // Clean up to avoid leaking memory
   for(size_t i=0; i<numLinesRead; i++) free(linesBuf[i]);
   free(linesBuf);

   return 0;
}
```

You can run this with stdin redirected from a file (e.g. `./a.out < input_file.txt`) or if you run it from a Terminal window, press Ctrl-D to indicate end-of-file to the program.

Comment: Or `Ctrl-Z` on windows...

Comment: I want to read all the input first then output it. I edited the question.

Comment: @JahirulSarker - so you want separate storage for each string so that after the read-loop you can access each string that was read?

Comment: Yes, I want to store all the strings and after that I want to print them altogether.

Comment: @JahirulSarker I've updated the example to store the text lines into an array.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner "Ctrl-D" is not working.